# How to make sure my Apache2 mod_mem_cache is working?

Tags: apache2

I just installed Apache2 with mod_mem_cache on it. What is the easiest way to confirm that the cache is really working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curl to I would think that using a utility like nmon that monitors memory usage would be useful. You will look for spikes in memory usage when you get a computer to hit the pages of your site.

Comment: Some of the comment got cut out when I had to log in. 


Use curl to hit your website a few hundred times while using a utility like nmon that monitors memory usage. You should take note of spikes in memory use as the mod chaches objects on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you should try phpinfo()and see if your answer is in there or simply do a stress test with a free app on you server and compare the load difference between on and off.